# HTML sidebar default open

Tags: html, default, show, sidebar

how can make it so my HTML pages sidebar would be default open? You should then be able to close and reopen the sidebar, but it should be default open. Currently I always have to click it open.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-color: #032e72;
  }
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00A2E8;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #002838;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s
  }
  .sidenav a:hover,
  .offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #EBF5FB;
  }
  .sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
</style>

<body bgcolor="#e0f6ff">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
    <a href="tuotteet.html">Tuotteet</a>
    <a href="tekijat.html">Ty&ouml;ntekij&auml;t</a>

    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p align="center">&copy; Huomisen Vanhus Oy 2016</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <img src="LOGO_2.png" style="width:800px;height:180px;">
    <br></br>

    <span style="font-size:25px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Valikko</span>

    <h2>Huomisen Vanhus Oy</h2>

    <font size="5" ; font color=#002838>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br> </br>

Aliquam et varius purus. Etiam scelerisque leo ac felis auctor, ac vestibulum eros imperdiet.
 </font>
  </div>


  <script>
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }

    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `openNav()` function at the end.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

// Call this at the end.
openNav();
```

And make sure to use `<br />`. There's no `<br></br>`.

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/wuliyuzuho**

Comment: @user2786413 Click on the link in my answer and see if it works for you. `:)`

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't need this additional call to 'openNav'. Shouldn't you just set the css so that it defaults to open? See my answer above.

Comment: @pulekies Sure... :)

Answer (score 0):

In the css you are setting the `width` and `margin-left` to be `0` initially. Set them to `250px` initially in the css and it will default to open.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
   font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; font-color: #032e72;
 }

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:  #00A2E8;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding-top: 60px;
 }

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #002838;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s
 }

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #EBF5FB;
 }

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
 }

#main  {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-left: 250px;
 }

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
 }
</style>

<body bgcolor="#e0f6ff">

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a>
  <a href="tuotteet.html">Tuotteet</a>
  <a href="tekijat.html">Ty&ouml;ntekij&auml;t</a>

<br> </br>
<br> </br>
<br> </br>
<p align="center"> &copy; Huomisen Vanhus Oy 2016</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
<img src="LOGO_2.png" style="width:800px;height:180px;">
<br> </br>

 <span style="font-size:25px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Valikko</span>

 <h2>Huomisen Vanhus Oy</h2>

 <font size="5"; font color=#002838 >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br> </br>

Aliquam et varius purus. Etiam scelerisque leo ac felis auctor, ac vestibulum eros imperdiet.
 </font>
</div>


<script>
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  }

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }


</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```